Hibernate mode not running since last update from Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Since the last update from Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS, my Thinkpad E16 Gen 2 (Intel® Core™ Ultra 7 155H × 22) won't go in the Hibernate mode anymore.
Is there a fix for that problem, or should I wait for the next update.

I would try booting a different (newer) kernel
version.  6.10rc3 is known to work well with Core Ultra.
